# Python - OpenCV - imread - Displaying Image

Tags: python, image, opencv, imshow

I am currently working on reading an image and displaying it to a window. I have successfully done this, but upon displaying the image, the window only allows me to see a portion of the
full image.  I tried saving the image after loading it, and it saved the entire image.  So I am fairly certain that it is reading the entire image.

```
imgFile = cv.imread('1.jpg')

cv.imshow('dst_rt', imgFile)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image:
[image]

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are using the old version (python module for the new one named `cv2`). Try to update it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using cv2 as cv.

Comment: This code looks fine. Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ug90J.jpg
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/qsJuF.jpg

Comment: It wouldn't let me add the images to my question, but here are links to the original image and a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like the image is too big and the window simply doesn't fit the screen.
Create window with the `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` flag, it will make it scalable. Then you can resize it to fit your screen like this:

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

screen_res = 1280, 720
scale_width = screen_res[0] / img.shape[1]
scale_height = screen_res[1] / img.shape[0]
scale = min(scale_width, scale_height)
window_width = int(img.shape[1] * scale)
window_height = int(img.shape[0] * scale)

cv2.namedWindow('dst_rt', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('dst_rt', window_width, window_height)

cv2.imshow('dst_rt', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[According to the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow) `CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` flag should do the same, yet it doesn't and it's value not even presented in the python module.

Comment: Use floating point screen_res to get a correctly scaled starting image: 
`screen_res = 1280., 720.`

Comment: @Marc `from __future__ import division` look it up

Comment: I needed to add `cv2.resize(img, (window_width, window_height)) ` before `cv2.imshow('dst_rt', img)`

Answer (score 3):

**This can help you**

```
namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.
```

Comment: Isn't it WINDOW_AUTOSIZE instead of CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE?

Answer (score 1):

In openCV whenever you try to display an oversized image or image bigger than your display resolution you get the cropped display. It's a default behaviour.
In order to view the image in the window of your choice openCV encourages to use named window. Please refer to [namedWindow documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow)

The function namedWindow creates a window that can be used as a placeholder for images and trackbars. Created windows are referred to by their names.

`cv.namedWindow(name, flags=CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)`
where each window is related to image container by the name arg, make sure to use same name

eg:

```
import cv2
frame = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow("Display 1")
cv2.resizeWindow("Display 1", 300, 300)
cv2.imshow("Display 1", frame)
```

Comment: Does it make sense to have `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` if you then explicitly invoke `resizeWindow()` ?

Comment: @javadba your right, `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` is not recommended when we explicitly invoke `resizeWindow()` thanks for catching that!