# OpenCV changes image shape when loading. Why?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

When using this command:

```
Mat im_gray = imread("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Blue.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

the image is not only loaded but its shape is changed.

This is the original image: [image: original image]

This is the resultant image when loading it :

[image: loaded image]

How can the image be loaded, while maintaining the same shape ?

Comment: It should not be changed. Try to use `imwrite()` to save it again to the disk to verify.

Comment: Just try NamedWindow with WINDOW_NORMAL option.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285562/python-opencv-imread-displaying-image)? Basically, the image was changing shape because it was too big for the screen. What happens if you rotate the image before you `imread()` it? Better yet, make it scalable like the answer I linked above and you should be good.

Comment: I've seen the link. The only thing I don't understand is img.shape[1] and img.shape[0] in the scale_width and scale_height variables. What are these calculating. Also, what could be changed for a C++ equivalent?

Comment: @user3050012 `img.shape[1]` is the width of your source image. `img.shape[0]` is the height of your source image.