# cv2.imshow() crashes Kernel

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, ipython, jupyter

I am running OpenCV through Jupyter Notebooks and whenever I try to run cv2.imshow() the kernel crashes, no error message or helpful hint - just a plain

> `The Kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

Here is the code I am running...

```
import cv2 
input = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Hello World', input)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code works (albeit differently) when I run the below...

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

FYI I am using a completely unaltered copy of BitFusion on AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0?ref=cns_srchrow

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: P.S. I am accessing the JN through Chrome running on Windows 7.

Comment: Matplotlib can render into images, which can then be displayed as part of the HTML notebook. The OpenCV convenience GUI utilities are purely client side -- `imshow` shows the image in a GUI window, `waitKey` pumps the message loop, etc. It doesn't make any sense running them on the server side.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem. The following answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285562/python-opencv-imread-displaying-image Make sure there aren't any syntax errors if it still crashes.

Answer (score 9):

I can't explain the behavior of your code right now but you can use the below code to achieve the above behavior.

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's not what the question asks. cv2. imshow() doesn't work. Using plt doesn't help the question.

Comment: Additionally, the matplotlib display will invert the colour channels and display a BGR image as RGB.

Answer (score 5):

To view images with `cv2.imshow` on AWS, you need to enable X11 forwarding so the graphics can be run on the server and displayed locally.  This can be done by ssh-ing with the `-Y` option:

```
ssh -Y username@hostname
```

If the images are larger, you will also need to compress the data using `-C`:

```
ssh -Y -C username@hostname
```

The terminal used to ssh into AWS will need to be left open as long as you're displaying images from the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

So for me, the issue was fixed by placing a while loop that ends when you press the key D on your keyboard

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv2.imread('Images/1.jpg')
while True: 
    cv.imshow('ImageDisplay',img)
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('d'):
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

update numpy !!

```
pip install -U numpy --user
```