# Jupyter kernel crashes when trying to display image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run the example from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-via-color-based-image-segmentation-using-python-e9b7c72f0e11)

```
import cv2

def viewImage(image):
    cv2.namedWindow('Display', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('Display', image)
    print('test')
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def grayscale_17_levels (image):
    high = 255
    while(1):  
        low = high - 15
        col_to_be_changed_low = np.array([low])
        col_to_be_changed_high = np.array([high])
        curr_mask = cv2.inRange(gray, col_to_be_changed_low,col_to_be_changed_high)
        gray[curr_mask > 0] = (high)
        high -= 15
        if(low == 0 ):
            break

image = cv2.imread('ombre_circle.png')
viewImage(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayscale_17_levels(gray)
viewImage(gray)
```

Whenever I run the code I get the error:

> Kernel Restarting
>   The kernel for main.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

I when I comment out these lines:

```
#cv2.namedWindow('Display', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#cv2.imshow('Display', image)
```

the core runs and prints out 'test' and I don't get an error.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu-server 18.04
- Jupyter lab 1.1.3
- opencv-python 4.1.1.26

I run this on a server not on my local environment

I found a workaround for this issue by displaying it with Matplotlib:

```
def viewImage(image):
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.title("RGB")
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()

image = cv2.imread('img/ombre_circle.png')
viewImage(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayscale_17_levels(gray)
viewImage3(cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
```

However this doesn't solve the issue and takes extra transformations/code so I would like to find a solution to display with opencv.

X11 forwarding is enabled.

I tried opening an SSH connection with the -Y and -C flag ([via this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943333/cv2-imshow-crashes-kernel#47604330)) but this doesn't fix it.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[IPython Github Issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8589)

What I understand from the discussion is that it's a C-level linking or runtime error from the openCV code being run.
I faced the same problem, got solved by using matplotlib [SO jupyternb crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236180/opencv-imshow-will-cause-jupyter-notebook-crash)

Answer (score 0):

image=cv2.imread("the file") 
cv2.imshow("test file", image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue when I'm loading large tiff files. Same code works for small tiff files. You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943333/cv2-imshow-crashes-kernel) post to compress your image then display.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.imshow()` would cause Jupyter sessions
to crash: [this post of the issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935).

As a substitution, please consider using
`from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` on Google Colab.