# Python code using Jupyter Notebook deployed on Azure . Issue: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, azure, opencv, deployment, jupyter-notebook

All of the script had been running perfectly fine in Jupyter Notebook. But, I am facing an issue "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" when I deploy python code using Jupyter Notebook on Azure. All parts of the code run fine, except for the last line of the code (where I open an image using OpenCV). Moreover, I have installed all necessary libraries.
This is the error message that I am getting:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

And, here is the skeleton of my Python Code:

```
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install numpy
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install -U numpy
!pip install ipykernel ipython jupyter_client jupyter_core traitlets ipython_genutils
!pip install numpy --upgrade
!pip install nomkl
!pip update --all
!apt-get update
!apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install -c intel mkl



import cv2
image=cv2.imread('img_1.jpg')
image.shape
image[0]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)

# from here I can get an error

while True:
   cv2.imshow('Image',image)
   if cv2.waitKey(2) == 27:
    # 27 is ASCII os Escape
    break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I solve this problem?

I checked some of the previous links on stackoverflow: [Jupyter | The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022997/jupyter-the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-it-will-restart-automatically)

I tried the solution given in the link, unfortunately, it has not worked for my case :(

Answer (score 0):

> Kernel Restarting
> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

I have got the same issue. I have fixed by **reinstalling** the necessary packages again. I hope you already done it if not try to reinstall the necessary packages **matplotlib, NumPy, TensorFlow & others.**

Instead of using **`!pip install opencv-python`** you can use **`pip install opencv-python--headless`**.

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943333/cv2-imshow-crashes-kernel) thread created by Mike de H for similar kind of issue.